# How to restrict for all the textbox entry throughout all my application - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/HGJb3/

HTML

```
<input class="anything" type="text">
<input type="text">
<input id="someid" type="text">
<input type="text">
<input id="someotherid" type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type ="text">
<br />
<br />
<br />
working one
<input id="text" type="text">
```

JS

```
$('#text').keypress(function (e) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (regex.test(str)) {
        return true;
    }    
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Now I want to apply this keypress function for all the text boxes not just last one. How to edit this function so that it works for all?

Can't put all of their Ids same.

have to make it work for @html.textBoxFor - can put datannootation in model thats why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this one to apply all input textbox: Fiddle [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HGJb3/567/)

[Fiddle example with popup](http://jsfiddle.net/HGJb3/568/)

```
$('input[type="text"]').keypress(function (e) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (regex.test(str)) {
        return true;
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: not able to make ti work if the textbox is in popup or partial view in asp.net

Comment: You can check it working with popup. fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/HGJb3/568/

Answer (score 1):

Like you said ( **Can't put all of their Ids same** ), this is not valid as per HTML because in a single page you cant use same Id for more than one element. Even though you will assign same Id to couple of elements but while fetching that element using id from client side, it will fetch the very first element found in DOM from TOP.

So in such scenarios assign one common class to all the textbox for which you want to apply that regex and then bind keypress event on that common class as selector.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HGJb3/566/)

HTML

```
<input class="textClass anything" type="text">
<input class="textClass" type="text">
<input class="textClass" id="someid" type="text">
<input class="textClass" type="text">
<input class="textClass" id="someotherid" type="text">
<input class="textClass" type="text">
<input class="textClass" type="text">
<br />
<br />
<br />
working one
<input class="textClass" id ="text" type="text">
```

JS

```
$('.textClass').keypress(function (e) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (regex.test(str)) {
        return true;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

I Hope this works for you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Just change your selector to "input:text" if you are using textbox 
$('input:text').keypress(function (e) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (regex.test(str)) {
        return true;
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```